# How to connect InfoWindow II to IBM 9406-250?

Tags: ibm, ibm-midrange

I received an old InfoWindow II (don't know the exact model number yet) from somebody, and want to connect it as a console for my IBM 9406-250 so I can do a manual IPL.

I am totally new to this, and I am still learning how to use everything, and was wondering what kind of cables/connectors I need to hook this up.

Here's the back of the 9406-250 with available connections:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is a twinax connector.

Comment: The InfoWindow II needs a Twinax Pigtail Cable to convert the DB15F to TwinAx. The 9406 looks like a 10Base2/AUI; and the other card looks like a line card of some kind, not sure exactly what you'd need there.

Comment: I actually don't see a Twinax port on the machine (though it might be cut off).  In any case, [IBM's instructions on how to do this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/powersys/v3r1m5/index.jsp?topic=/iphbx/installcable.htm) will probably be helpful. If you need a Twinax console cable you can get the IBM part number [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/powersys/v3r1m5/index.jsp?topic=/iphad/allcabl.htm), but a 3rd party vendor will probably be cheaper for buying the actual cable.